# Is there a pig / hadoop property that can be set for PIG_HEAPSIZE?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

spark, hadoop, tez, etc. all have a list of properties that can be manually configured. example:

yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb

or

spark.executor.memory

or

pig.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer,
pig.exec.reducers.max

....

Is there an equivalent for PIG_HEAPSIZE? It seems like it can only be set via the environment variable. what is this environment variable doing behind the scenes? which properties is it affecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pig relies on an execution engine such as Tez, Spark, or Mapreduce, so it would inherit the heap sizes from those configurations, such as the Spark executor memory, rather than use its own.

The only thing that `PIG_HEAPSIZE` controls is the [local JVM driver process](https://github.com/apache/pig/blob/trunk/bin/pig#L143-L148) where you run the `pig` command, therefore it only should be a local env-var, not a remote configuration property.

Comment: thank you for the quick answer! as a followup question, is it possible for the tez/spark/mr memory configurations to conflict with what is set at PIG_HEAPSIZE? say I set the tez memory to 8GB and then the PIG_HEAPSIZE to 32GB, will there be an internal configuration error?

Comment: There should not be. Tez tasks run within YARN, for example. As answered `PIG_HEAPSIZE` only applies to the local machine where you run `pig` CLI (which could be a remote node, not part of YARN)